# Accessing regexs in arrays to use for form validation

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing 2 dimensional arrays storing regexes for form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767779/accessing-2-dimensional-arrays-storing-regexes-for-form-validation)

I am trying to loop through form fields and validate against regexes stored in arrays. Can't see what is wrong here. Any ideas please? Sorry my first question contained no code!!!

```
  if(window.addEventListener){
   window.addEventListener("load",initVal,false);
   }else if (window.attachEvent){
   window.attachEvent("onload",initVal);
   } else { window.onload=initVal;}

   function initVal() {
   document.orderform.postcode.onchange=checkAll;
   document.orderform.email.onchange=checkAll;
       }
   function checkAll(){ 

  frmflds= new Array (2);
         for (i=0;i<frmflds.length;i++) {
            frmflds [i] = new Array (2);
  frmflds[0][0] = 'postcode';
          frmflds[0][1] = '/^[A-z][A-z]\d{2}\s\d{2}[A-z][A-z]|[A-z][A-z]\d{1}\s\d{1}[A-z][A-z]$/';
          frmflds[1][0] = 'email';
          frmflds[1][1] = '/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/'; }
 for(var j = 0; j < frmflds.length; j++) {
    var e = frmflds[j][0][1];
    var OK= (e.exec(document.orderform.getElementById()[j].name.value);
    if !OK
    {
     document.orderform.name[j].style.borderColor="red";
     document.orderform.name[j].style.backgroundColor="pink";
     document.orderform.Submit.onclick.disabled=true;
     alert("Please correct any highlighted fields and submit again!");
     }           
    else{
     document.orderform.name[j].style.borderColor="Green";
     document.orderform.name[j].style.backgroundColor="PaleGreen";
     document.orderform.Submit.onclick.disabled=false;
   }            
    }   }                  
   //]]></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <form method="post" action=""" name="orderform" id="orderfm">
   <p><input type="text"  name="postcode" id="postcode" ></p>
   <p><input type="text" name="email" id="email" ></p>
   <p><input label="" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" disabled="disabled"> 
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```